# Help finding a word that means "made tangible"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I know there is a word for this, but I can't figure it out. I think it sounds like "mortalized". It means "brought into existence" in a tangible way.

For example, the Iliad and the Odyssey were just stories before Homer wrote them down. He _______ them.

Thank you so much!

It's not anything like "published". It specifically refers to something that was previously an oral tradition or unwritten, and finally someone _____ them.

Comment: ‘recorded’?  But why the insistence on a single word?  What is wrong with ‘wrote them down’?

Comment: You could very well use *immortalised*: by writing them down, they could no longer die with the only people who knew how to tell the stories.

Comment: If you've got an answer to your own question, feel free to post it as a proper answer, including a links to dictionary entries or usage examples, if possible. You can even accept your own question - that's [explicitly encouraged](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) by Stack Exchange. (You may need to accrue at least 15 rep points first, though.)

Comment: Shed a tear for Homer, suffering the linguistic indignity of externalization!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If others are looking for additional words, here are a few possibilities.

- manifested
- developed
- created
- evinced
- embodied
- materialized

Comment: @braelyn2 You're welcome. I really do love my print edition of Roget's Thesaurus.